# Can a simple voltage divider circuit be used to accurately measure voltage?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

I have a discharger circuit that I intend to hook up to a 3V battery. Total resistance of the circuit (depending on how fast I intend to discharge it) will vary from 0.04 to 0.01 Ohms (that's 75A and 450A respectively).

Can I hook up a simple voltage divider circuit in parallel to measure the 'health' of the battery? (Diagram below) Or will I run into some trouble?

[image]

Thanks,

Julia

Comment: How do you intend to measure the voltage? You "measurement" device can have an input resistance comparable to the resistor values, effectively changing the voltage divider.

Comment: Indeed. 5Mohm will introduce *considerable* error when used with a typical 10Mohm DMM.

Comment: It's a 3V battery - why don't you just measure it directly using an MCU with 5V ADC facilities?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was going to read it via this guy's IO pins: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9669

Comment: What kind of battery are we talking about?  You have a battery which can supply 900 watts of power (3V at 300A) for a meaningful length of time, but it's only 3 volts?

Comment: I don't understand why you think you want the voltage divider at just 3V.

Comment: @supercat, yes I have a LiFePO4 prismatic 200Ah cell. I don't understand Majenko's question, sorry

Comment: @jules0075: Many analog inputs will have no difficulty measuring voltages up to 3 volts, so I think his question is why not use such an input and avoid the need to use a voltage divider.  Given the size of your batteries, I would think that the current drawn when using a couple of 10K or even 1K resistors would be a relative non-factor, especially since your apparent *goal* is to drain the batteries in less than an hour.

Comment: I'm sure this is just a typo, but 0.01 ohms will not give you 450 amps out of a 3V battery

Comment: Sorry, @krb686, that was a typo indeed.

Comment: Okay, I was wondering if connecting it directly would be dangerous in some way. I have a contactor in series with the battery & resistor banks, but it has a TVS diode across it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divider has an output impedance of 2.5M ohm, so it should not be connected directly to the ADC or you'll get considerable error.

Why not use 10K + 10K 1%?

Edit: According to the [manual](http://www.canakit.com/Media/Manuals/UK1104.pdf) you linked in your comments, the maximum source impedance allowable for the board you have in mind (it appears to use a PIC) is 10K ohms.

[image]

So 10K + 10K is fine, and you could use a higher value if you like (as much as 20K+20K if you always have the battery connected) or stick with the 10K+10K if you might put a switch in there to reduce drain on the battery.

Comment: Tbh I chose random values thinking it wouldn't matter. Can you please explain why 10K resistors would work better?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, do you mean source impedance of 5K?

Comment: 10K resistors will look like a 5K ohm source impedance to the ADC input, well within the acceptable range. They will draw more current from the battery, of course, about 150uA. –  Spehro Pefhany 4 hours ago

Comment: @ScottSeidman Yes, of course, thanks for the correction.